# A question on the electrostrong force

Tags: beyond-the-standard-model, carrier-particles, grand-unification

I understand that the strong nuclear force is carried by gluons, the electromagnetic force is carried by photons and the weak nuclear force is carried by the $W$ and $Z$ bosons. However, in the electrostrong epoch, which particle carried the [electrostrong force](https://www.google.com/search?as_epq=electrostrong+force)? Does a grand unified theory tell us?

Comment: 1. What theory of unification of the strong and electromagnetic forces are you assuming here? There is no unique accepted GUT. 2. What, exactly, do you expect from an answer except saying "the particle(s) carrying the electrostrong force"?

Comment: @ACuriousMind Let's assume the GUT is the Georgi Glashow model ,which uses SU(5).

Comment: @ACuriousMind I would like to know the name of the particle and its properties (such as mass, charge, spin etc.)

Comment: It's a force carrier, so why would it be any different from the other gauge bosons in unbroken gauge theories like the photon or the gluon (i.e. massless, spin 1, charges appropriate for the adjoint rep of the gauge group)?

Comment: @ACuriousMind The other gauge bosons carry individual forces that separated from the electrostrong force, so I thought there is a hypothetical particle that used to carry the electrostrong force.

Comment: see this  presentation ,  https://www-zeuthen.desy.de/~blumlein/Talks/GUT.pdf page 17 for the gauge bosons

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quote from The Entire History of the Universe, The Ultimate Guide - How did the Universe begin?

Some scientist believe that the decay of the X boson messenger particles that carried the Electrostrong Force created a strong inflation field carried by a new messenger particle called the Inflaton. This overwhelming new inflation energy may have driven exponential expansion, which saw quantum scale irregularities almost instantly scaled up to large-scale structure.